# Unexpected "division by zero: 0 / 0" error on BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm working with a Google Ads dataset that is updated daily on BQ. The query was working fine last week, however, when I tried to run it today, I got an error:

> division by zero: 0/0

[image]

Really not sure what I did wrong to get the error because I haven't touched this query since last week. I've already tried `SAFE_DIVIDE`, but still the same result. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try SAFE_DIVIDE in both divisions?

Comment: Last week you didn't have the same data? The error itself is quite obvious, you're dividing with zero.

Answer (score 1):

Data keeps changing all the time so you need to test the values before you divide

Try **Safe_divide**

> Also : https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-nullif/